# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException and Inner Exception SqlException: Invalid column name 'xxxx'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-6

This is regarding an exception when trying to fetch values to a Datagrid from a database.

When I try to run the application I got the below-mentioned error as,

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception
> SqlException: Invalid column name 'AssetClass_Id'.

This above mentioned foreign key column `AssetClass_Id` has been modified as `AssetClassId` when updating the database from migration. The database shows its column value as `AssetClassId` in the design too.

Here is my `AssetType` class code:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public AssetClass AssetClass { get; set; }
```

Here is my .cs file code which written under form load method:

```
using (CapexDbContext db = new CapexDbContext())
{
    // Load data to grdAssetType
    assetTypeBindingSource.DataSource = db.AssetTypes.ToList();
    AssetType obj = assetTypeBindingSource.Current as AssetType;
    panelAssetType.Enabled = false;

    // Load data to cmbAssetClasses
    var assetClass_ = from AssetClass in db.AssetClasses
                      select AssetClass;

    cmbAssetClass.DataSource = assetClass_.ToList();
    cmbAssetClass.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbAssetClass.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

The exception coming from this line when trying to fetch data to the dataGrid:

```
assetTypeBindingSource.DataSource = db.AssetTypes.ToList();
```

Additionally here is my latest migration code:

```
         CreateTable(
            "dbo.AssetClasses",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Code = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Lifetime = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Rate = c.Single(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AssetTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    AssetClassId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AssetClasses", t => t.AssetClassId)
            .Index(t => t.AssetClassId);
```

Running DB Tables : AssetTypes & AssetClass(referring table)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably your database is not updated as your models. Use `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands.

Comment: Be sure you're connected to the corrrect DB. I had this problem when I was trying to connect to the production database that had been changed, but I was connected to the development one instead, which was not changed. Changed regarding my app code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a look to the DBcontext in your project, try to see waht it does say in the definition of the entity, especialy in this part:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("user");
    
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("user");
        entity.Property(e => e.CreationAtDate)
        .HasColumnName("created_at") //<------ THIS ONE
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getDate())");
    });
```

Comment: My DBContext doesnt have any OnModelCreating method....

Comment: I thought that even with migrations you need OnModelCreating, maybe is not the case. Can you share a screenshot of the table in the running db?

Comment: Try to Scaffold the DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `AssetType` class contains `AssetClass` property.

Meanwhile, the table in your database contains the `AssetClassId` field.

They are different.

Therefore, we should define the class in the `AssetType` class.

```
 public class AssetType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int AssetClassID { get; set; }    // We need to modify it here
    }
```

Then, we need to execute the command to update the database in the package manager console.

```
PM> Add-Migration Modify

PM> Update-Database
```

Finally, we can use the following code to show data in the datagirdview.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {

                var type = new AssetType { Id = 1001, Description = "test1", Name = "name1", AssetClassID=123456 };
                db.Types.Add(type);
                db.SaveChanges();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = db.AssetTypes.ToList();
              
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]